# Writing .htaccess for profile username that appends an integer

Tags: php, .htaccess, mysqli

Hi there I have a single page called `profile.php` that I'm using to interchange between user profiles.  Once a user is created through registration, a username is created based on their name and is used to access the page.  ex. ricky_lake, tom_brown etc.  I'm using the following `.htaccess` file for this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0_9-]+)$ profile.php?profile_username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0_9-]+)/$ profile.php?profile_username=$1
```

This is all working fine except when the profile name contains a number.  It's necessary to append in some cases, so we don't have duplicates in the dB.  I have the number appending in `register.php` as follows:

```
//Generate username by concatenating first name and last name
$username = strtolower($fname . "_" . $lname);
$check_username_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");

$i = 0;
//if username exists add number to username
while (mysqli_num_rows($check_username_query) != 0) {
    $i++; //Add 1 to i
    $username = $username . "_" . $i;
    $check_username_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'"); 
}
```

If one were to sign up again as Tom Brown this would return tom_brown_1, or the next tom_brown_2.  etc.

The problem is, the only one that comes up is tom_brown.  When I add the integer on, it throws an `Error 404`.  The profile itself is in the dB as expected and all else seems to be fine (able to login, make posts etc), except cannot open profile page.  I'm thinking this has something to do with `.htaccess`, but from the above I can't spot the issue.  Been at this awhile now...Help! :)

Comment: The "0_9" In your regex should read "0-9", as it is, it only accepts 0 and 9 as integer.

Comment: I re-wrote it like this `[a-zA-Z-_0-9]+` and it works, thanks for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work; I also combine the two rules to one, with the ? after the regex and slash it makes it optional. I also edited the regex.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)/?$ profile.php?profile_username=$1
```

You can also do simple testing with; 
https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: nice.  It works both ways now, but `[a-zA-Z-_0-9]+` was the culprit.